# Tortoise SVN repair move menu item not found

Tags: tortoisesvn

I'v heard of [Repair Remane/Move](http://tortoisesvn.net/repairmoves.html) feature in Tortoise SVN. I have installed the latest version of TSVN, but I still don't see that item in the context menu. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the article you link to states, that feature is there to repair folders/files within the working copy that have been moved using the operating system's file manager rather than by using TortoiseSVN, meaning that until you repair the move or rename it's not being tracked by TortoiseSVN. TortoiseSVN will only give you the repair option if you're right clicking on such a file.

If you have a working copy open, move or rename a file within windows explorer then right click on it with TSVN - the option should show up.

-- edited --
The actual steps for the solution are in comments

Comment: Sorry, but that does not work for me. Do I have to click TortoiseSVN->Add first? I tried right-clicking the moved file before and after adding it to version control, but in both cases the "repair move" menu item was not displayed

Comment: Ah, beg pardon - yes, the files will need to be both added to version control, and then moved or renamed using windows file explorer (rather than the tortoiseSVN move and rename commands). If you do both those things then right click on one of the moved/renamed files the option to repair will show in the tortoiseSVN context menu.
ETA: Not sure about this but I suspect it'll also have to be moved somewhere else within the current working copy, not outside of it.

Comment: I still don't see that menu item. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you open the commit dialogue and check the list of changes there, it should show the moved files as changed - I believe if you right click in that dialogue box it should offer you the repair move option?

Comment: Finally I found how to do it. The deleted file must be listed as "deleted" rather than "missing". To achieve this, in Commit dialog I need to right-click the missing file and click "delete". Than select both deleted and added file. Than "Repair move" action is available.

Comment: So, to sum up, this is how it's done:
First, the file under the new name has to be added to version control.

Then, the deleted file must be listed as "deleted" rather than "missing". To achieve this, in Commit dialog you need to right-click the missing file and select "delete".

Finally, in Commit dialog select both files, the deleted one and the added one. Then "Repair move" action will be available on right-click.

Comment: I tried this and I receive the helpful error message "Access Denied".